# Can this style of carousel be done with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a Flash-based gallery: http://spin.co.uk
I love the way it works, but Flash isn't an option for me.

I've had a look at various plugins but couldn't find any demo or indication that this kind of setup is even possible. I don't need to jump between slides, just backwards/forwards.

Could anybody help me out? Thanks!

Comment: It's ok, but I find it frustrating to browse. I gave up after about a minute trying to get a feel for what those guys do.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible, you could take a look at jQuery Tools' [Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html) plugin.

Comment: is right, certainly possible to do but will also most likely require a bunch of custom code such as custom in/out animations triggering AJAX loads of the next set of slides etc. Then while inside a set of slides use something like Scrollable to animate to and from individual slides.

Comment: I've got the basic Scrollable working, but I can't figure out how to position the next slide. It seems all slides need to be relatively positioned with even spacing, whereas I'd like them to be **positioned as _fixed_**.